# UWP C++ ContentDialog PrimaryButtonCommand or PrimaryButtonClick

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I'm trying to use `ContentDialog^` in a UWP C++ app. With `MessageDialog^`
you can easily set the buttons and commands `Windows::UI::Popups::UICommand` they invoke when touched

```
MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog("Data changed - Save?");
msg->Title = "Warning";

// Add commands and set their callbacks.
UICommand^ continueCommand = ref new UICommand("Yes", ref new UICommandInvokedHandler(this, &MainPage::CommandInvokedHandler));
UICommand^ upgradeCommand = ref new UICommand("No", ref new UICommandInvokedHandler(this, &MainPage::CommandInvokedHandler));
UICommand^ cancelCommand = ref new UICommand("Cancel", ref new UICommandInvokedHandler(this, &MainPage::CommandInvokedHandler));
```

then you can easily access the value sent to the `CommandInvokedHandler` by

```
void MainPage::CommandInvokedHandler(Windows::UI::Popups::IUICommand^ command)
{
    // Display message
    if (command->Label == "Yes") {
        Save();
    } else if (command->Label == "No") {
        Skip();
    } else if (command->Label == "Cancel") {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

However, the content dialog works completely differently. It's created like this

```
TextBox^ inputTextBox = ref new TextBox();
inputTextBox->AcceptsReturn = false;
inputTextBox->Height = 32;
ContentDialog^ dialog = ref new ContentDialog();

dialog->Content = inputTextBox;
dialog->Title = "Rename";
dialog->IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = true;
dialog->PrimaryButtonText = "Ok";
dialog->SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel";
dialog->ShowAsync();
```

I either need to set the property `dialog->PrimaryButtonCommand` that for some (unknown bizarre) reason uses the completely different `Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::ICommand`...
Or should I use the `dialog->PrimaryButtonClick`?

I'm struggling to find any C++ examples anywhere and the documentation doesn't clear anything up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [PrimaryButtonCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonCommand) or [PrimaryButtonClick](http://Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonCommand) in [ContentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog). Both of them will be invoked when the primary button has been tapped. The difference between them is that `PrimaryButtonClick` is a [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/events-c-cx), but `PrimaryButtonCommand` is a property whose type is [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand). Please note [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand) is not the same as [U​ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.uicommand) used in `MessageDialog`, they are totally two different things.

[ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand) is more used with XAML Binding. To use it, we will implement [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand) interface and then use in view model. For more info, please refer to [Executing commands in a view model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160324.aspx#Executing_commands_in_a_view_model).

And in your case, as you are creating content dialog in code-behind, so I think you can just subscribe to `PrimaryButtonClick` event with an event handler method like the following:

```
void MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    TextBox^ inputTextBox = ref new TextBox();
    inputTextBox->AcceptsReturn = false;
    inputTextBox->Height = 32;
    ContentDialog^ dialog = ref new ContentDialog();

    dialog->Content = inputTextBox;
    dialog->Title = "Rename";
    dialog->IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = true;
    dialog->PrimaryButtonText = "Ok";
    dialog->SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel";
    dialog->PrimaryButtonClick += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialog ^, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs ^>(this, &MainPage::OnPrimaryButtonClick);
    dialog->ShowAsync();
}


void MainPage::OnPrimaryButtonClick(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialog ^sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs ^args)
{
    // Do something useful here
}
```